# Python Error: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python

I am an R User that is trying to learn more about Python.

I found this Python library that I would like to use for address parsing: https://github.com/zehengl/ez-address-parser

I was able to try an example over here:

```
from ez_address_parser import AddressParser

ap = AddressParser()

result = ap.parse("290 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9")
print(results)
[('290', 'StreetNumber'), ('Bremner', 'StreetName'), ('Blvd', 'StreetType'), ('Toronto', 'Municipality'), ('ON', 'Province'), ('M5V', 'PostalCode'), ('3L9', 'PostalCode')]
```

I have the following file that I imported:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/my_file.csv',  encoding='latin-1')

   name                               address
1 name1 290 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9
2 name2 291 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9
3 name3 292 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9
```

I then applied the above function and export the file and everything works:

```
df['Address_Parse'] = df['ADDRESS'].apply(ap.parse)

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/python_file.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

**Problem:** I now have another file (similar format) - but this time, I am getting an error:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/my_file1.csv',  encoding='latin-1')
df1['Address_Parse'] = df1['ADDRESS'].apply(ap.parse)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I am confused as to why the same code will not work for this file. As I am still learning Python, I am not sure where to begin to debug this problem. My guesses are that perhaps there are special characters in the second file, formatting issues or incorrect variable types that are preventing this `ap.parse` function from working, but I am still not sure.

Can someone please show me what to do?

Thank you!

Comment: is that AttributeError line all you are getting for your error message? If not, please post the whole error with stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! here is the full error: https://shrib.com/#Hippopotamus6VRWXYV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code from the library, we have this method for `parse` in the `AddressParser` class, and then this function for `tokenize` that is called by `parse`

```py
# method of AddressParser
def parse(self, address):
        if not self.crf:
            raise RuntimeError("Model is not loaded")

        tokens = tokenize(address)
        labels = self.crf.predict([transform(address)])[0]
        return list(zip(tokens, labels))

def tokenize(s):
    s = s.replace("#", " # ")
    return [token for token in split(fr"[{puncts}\s]+", s) if token]
```

We can see here that `tokenize` calls `replace`, and so that is likely where your error is coming from. `tokenize` is probably expecting a `str` here (not a float), and that `s.replace()` is almost certainly for a string replacement.

So, your column likely has floats in it when it expects strings. The `tokenize` function should probably handle that better, but now it is up to you.

You should be able to resolve this by forcing your Address column to be strings (pandas will call it 'object').

```py
df1['string_address'] = df1['ADDRESS'].astype(str)
df1['Address_Parse'] = df1['string_address'].apply(ap.parse)
```

Comment: I know in the R programming language, there is a way to check the variable types of all variables in a dataset. This is done using the following command: str(df1).

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this in Python?

Comment: `df.info()` will print out a little view of all the columns and the datatypes of each.

Answer (score 1):

You can try read the csv file all in string by adding the `dtype=str`

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/my_file1.csv', encoding='latin-1', dtype=str)
```

Comment: @ BlackKat: thank you so much! What is different about adding "dtype=str"?

Comment: @antonoyaro8: by default, pd.read_csv will try to get the correct column type, in your data, maybe ADDRESS value is all number, so the type is float --> which cause the exception. Add dtype="str" force all column types to string.

Comment: As a note, this will read all columns as a string. If you want to override the default for reading just one or some columns, you would use a dictionary as the value there, like `pd.read_csv(file,...,dtype={'ADDRESS':str,other_col:int,...}`.